# Visual Studio Regular Expressions - Matching first word in a file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to match the first word in a file using Visual Studio Regex?

e.g. ^using matches multiple statements where "using" matches the first five characters on a line.

I need to find and replace the only first using statement where "using" matches the first five characters in the file.

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 1):

Well, regex matches against a string. So, you could try reading the first line of the file into a string and execute a regex match against that string.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  I meant Visual Studio Regex in Find/Replace.  I would like to match the first line only - something that will exclude subsequent lines like [^\nusing].  However [^\n] matches at least one character.